# Class cannot be found

Tags: c#

I'm utterly bamboozled by an app I'm trying to write which has suddenly stopped recognising one of my classes.

I don't see there being a hell of a lot of complex stuff here, so what could I possibly doing wrong?  My problem is that my Ticket class no longer appears to be able to see my CallStatus class.  Suggestions are SO welcome right now.

Code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Iesi.Collections.Generic;
using NHibernate.Search.Attributes;

namespace OpenDesk.Models
{
    [Indexed]
    public class Ticket
    {
        [DocumentId]
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }

        [Field]
        public virtual string ReferenceID { get; set; }
        public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual CallPriority Priority { get; set; }
        public virtual CallCategory Category { get; set; }
        public virtual CallStatus Status { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual CallType Type { get; set; }
        public virtual Detail Detail { get; set; }
        public virtual CallSource Source { get; set; }

        [NHibernate.Search.Attributes.IndexedEmbedded]
        public virtual ISet<CallType> Types { get; set; }
        public virtual ISet<CallCategory> Categories { get; set; }

    }
}



using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Iesi.Collections.Generic;
using NHibernate.Search.Attributes;

namespace OpenDesk.Models
{
    public class CallStatus
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Other code provided as needed.

> **Compilation error**:
>   Error 2 The type or namespace name 'CallStatus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   *C:\Users\Phil\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\OpenDesk\trunk\Source\OpenDesk\Models\Ticket.cs*

Comment: can you post the exact compilation error that you are getting? Also, physically, are both these classes in the same file / assembly?

Comment: Do you get a compile-time error? If so, what?

Comment: Yes, they're the same assembly (there's only one right now, apart from unit testing).  Compilation error is: Error    2    The type or namespace name 'CallStatus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\Phil\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\OpenDesk\trunk\Source\OpenDesk\Models\Ticket.cs    22    24    OpenDesk

Comment: What happens if you move the `CallStatus` class declaration inside `Ticket.cs`?

Comment: @Darin - Genius.  Why did I not think of that?  Put that as the answer and I'll mark it accepted.  So obvious, I completely didn't even think to try it.

Comment: I think there is some problem in this path "trunk\Source\OpenDesk\Models". Your folder structure and namespace name not same. Hope it will help.

Comment: @Phil, posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you move the `CallStatus` class declaration inside `Ticket.cs`?